# Import photo to imageview

Tags: ios, swift, upload, imageview

I need to do, that user can upload photos from a photo(from device) into imageView.

Add an action button?

How it works?

Comment: What you are asking? And what what have you done so far in support?

Comment: my english to bad. Sory. My goal - import image from photo(from device) to imageView object on my ViewController.

Comment: I hope you just really don't know which keywords to start. Search around "UIImagepickercontroller". People here would like you to show more efforts on the problem before you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have sample code form Apple Developer service: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html)

This sample app inserting chosen image form Image Picker into UIImageView.
Please analyze this sample, it should help you resolve your problem.

And here you have some related tutorial: [UIImagePickerController tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/)